# Python sending simultanoues wgets to localhost

Tags: python, wget, python-multithreading

I have written a python program in which I need to send n number of simultaneous wget requests to a localhost. I had implemented it using a for loop, but the requests will be sent sequentially instead of in parallel. Here is the code snippet:

```
1: for i in range(1,clients):
2:       for j in range(1,i):
3:         host = net.get('h%s'%(j))
4:         VAR = host.cmd('wget -O - 10.0.0.254 2>&1')
5:         mbps = re.search(r'\d+-\d+-\d+ \d+:\d+:\d+ ,VAR)
```

I am a beginner and don't know much about threading.

Please suggest how can I send simultaneous wget requests.

Thanks.

Comment: Python has a pretty nice module called [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for things like this. You'll want to make a `Queue`, spawn a bunch of `Process`es that add their result to this queue, wait for them all to finish, then handle the results.

Answer (score 0):

Or use threads through either threading or thread module. Put your code in a function, use queue (real queue from Queue module or a simple list) and run your loop so that it starts all needed threads.

Wait for all threads to join the main one and process the data in the queue.

Be warned that it's not advisable to start too many threads at once. E.g. over few hundrets if they are heavy. OS might even not permit it.

That stands for multiprocessing module too as it uses threads as well.

And, why would you like to use wget when you have Python library urllib2?

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

# In the 'J' loop:
u = urlopen("http://10.0.0.254")
response = u.read()
u.close()
# Do something with the response.
```

And, in your 'J' loop you have a formating error. You tryed to push int into str:

```
"h%s" % (j)
```

It should be:

```
"h%i" % j
```

Bare in mind that any kind of parallelisation wouldn't allow requests to arrive to host in order you tell it to.
Some threads may be processed before the others. There is no easy way to know how will scheduler process them.

But as you asked for parallel requests, i think you know that already.